# How to fix 'browser.takeScreenshot' proxy error?

Tags: typescript, protractor, screenshot, webdriver-manager

I have some automation tests in cucumber protractor but suddenly the 'browser.takeScreenshot' method is failing from today morning with the following error:

```
     WebDriverError: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
           <html><head>
           <title>502 Proxy Error</title>
           </head><body>
           <h1>Proxy Error</h1>
           <p>The proxy server received an invalid
           response from an upstream server.<br />
           The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a         
     href="/wd/hub/session/29068642-008c-4e84-9f12-           
     e2896a9c6b3e/screenshot">GET&nbsp;/wd/hub/session/29068642-008c-4e84- 
     9f12-e2896a9c6b3e/screenshot</a></em>.<p>
           Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p>                
     </p>
           </body></html>
```

Update: It's working in local, problem only appears if i run the tests on the selenium server.

Answer (score 0):

## Probable cause

Your browser has updated, and no longer functions with the protocol used by your version of the test driver.

## Fix

- Easier Option: Update the test framework.
- Harder Option: Roll back the version of the browser you are testing and pin it.